# How to compute this double integral with $dt$ and $dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate the following integral? Any help is appreciated because I am not sure if there are some theorems I haven't learned to solve the question. Thanks.

$\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx $

where $f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} dt$

---

I just found the solution of the first two steps and it's as the following
And it is more confusing to me now.

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \int_1^x \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} dt dx  $

$= -\int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} dt \int_t^0  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx $

$= -2\int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt $

... (From this step on, I guess I could solve it by letting $t=u^2$)

Comment: Just change the order of integration.

Comment: Are you sure, that $f(x)=\int_1^x \ldots$? It seems like it should go from $0$ to $x$ or from $x$ to $1$?

Comment: Yes, I just type the question exactly as in the book

Comment: @USER408858 The book is probably trying to trip is up there. Of course, we need to use $\int_1^x=-\int_x^1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\sqrt{x}}\,dt\,dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\sqrt{x}}\,dt\,dx$$.

Now you have to change the order of integration.

If you look at the $x-t$ plane then we are integrating over the triangle

Then the limits become:-

$$-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\sqrt{x}}\,dx\,dt$$.

Now you can integrate with $x$ first keeping $t$ as a constant

So the integral becomes :-

$$-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{t}}dt$$.

Now we would like to use the Maclauirin expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ in $0<|x|<1$.

$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}x^{r}}{r}$.

So we get $$-4\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(-1)^{r-1}\frac{t^{r-\frac{1}{2}}}{r}\,dt=-4\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r(r+\frac{1}{2})}$$

$$=8\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{r}\frac{1}{2r(2r+1)}=8\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{2r}-8\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{2r+1}$$.

The above step was possible as both sums are convergent by Leibnitz Test.

The 2nd sum is nothing but $$8\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{2r+1}=8\left(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-.....\right)$$.

If you are familiar with the maclaurin expansion of $\arctan(x)$ . Then you will see that it is nothing but $8(\arctan(1)-1)=2\pi-8$ . (This is also a well known series represesntation of $\pi$.

The 1st sum is just $4\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r}}{r}$. This is nothing but the Maclaurin expansion of $-2\ln(1+x)$ evaluated at $x=1$. So it is $-4\ln(2)$.

Hence we have our answer as :-

$$8-2\pi-4\ln(2)$$.

**Edit:-
A simple IBP would work totally fine. It was silly of me to invoke such complicated techniques.**

if you make the sub $t=u^{2}$ then you have $-4\int_{0}^{1}\ln(1+u^{2})\,du$.
Now apply IPB to easily solve this.

Comment: I did that exactly. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @RAHUL . No I am not talking about using IBP to just reduce the double integral to the integral. I am talking about using IBP to solve the integral of $\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{t}}$. The op most probably is not familiar with use of Dominated Convergence Theorem or concepts of radius of convergence. So that is why I wanted to evaluate the integral using elementary techniques rather than Maclaurin expansion. You have also used the dirichlet eta function which is unnecessary .

Answer (score 1):

$$2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$
By parts leads to,
$$-2\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)\sqrt{x}dx$$
Since $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that,
$$f'(x)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$$
Putting that expression inside our integral we have that,
$$-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
By the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ we have,
$$-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-\frac{1}{2}}dx$$
$$-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k(k+0.5)}$$
$$-4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k(2k+1)}$$
By partial fraction decomposition,
$$-4\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} -2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\right)$$
The both series can be evaluated,
First series can be solved with Dirichlet eta function,
$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}$$
It converges for all $\Re(s)>0$.
Second series can be computed by subtracting all the even terms from the Dirichlet eta function evaluated at $1$.
Sum of all even terms is half the total sum.
Now you compute it.